# get particular child element ID with selected the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout js for binding,i want to get child element ID,when i select the checkbox,my parent ID is generated by unique ID,how to achieve this

```
//this div is inside the for each loop

<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'unique_' + $index()},fav:  ({item:someItem})" class="Tab">

 // i need to get this itemIDs when i selecte the check box
   <div id=randon_item1><div>
   <div id=random_item2><div>
   <div id=random_item3><div>
   <div id=random_item4><div>
   </div>
    <input id="ckh1" type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(), click:      $root.toggleAssociation" />


 //toggleAssociation//
 self.toggleAssociation = function (item, event) {
 here i am getting the item and all parent div with unique_0 ID which will   be incremented for others div
 how i can get child element ID which is generated randomly
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with knockout.js, but it appears you have some typos in  your child elements id attributes, and you may want to contain that checkbox in the parent div with the class of "Tab" like this:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'unique_' + $index()}, fav: ({item:someItem})" class="Tab">

    <div id="random_item1"></div>
    <div id="random_item2"></div>
    <div id="random_item3"></div>
    <div id="random_item3"></div>

    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(), click: $root.toggleAssociation" />

</div>
```

Then your function:

```
self.toggleAssociation = function (item, event) {
    alert(event.target.parentNode.id);
}
```

or jQuery:

```
self.toggleAssociation = function (item, event) {
    alert($(event).parent().attr(id));
}
```

if you want each of those "random_item" id's then you can iterate over them in your self.toggleAssociation function:

```
$(event).siblings('div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, I corrected that, I rewrote everything and missed those. Thanks.

Comment: @thanks for your time ],this really solved my problems